# How to disable mDNS correctly?

Tags: macos, command-line, launchd

I work for a company and they asked me to disabled this mDNS for all the Macs.

I've tried:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSresponder.plist
```

Result:
`Unload failed: 150: Operation not permitted while System Integrity Protection is engaged`

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

Result: Nothing at all

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponderHelper
```

Result: I can disable this one.

I have also read that is not possible to disable mDNS is that correct?

Comment: All of you editing my question, no one answering, thanks

Comment: There is an anwer below, doesn't this work for you?

Comment: I know it might be difficult, but I would ask the company why they want to do this. If mDNS polling is hurting their network, they've got bigger problems.

Comment: See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/344163 for related answers. Please be aware that `mDNS` on macOS is not optional; applications and processes will assume it exists and works. This includes local-only look-ups for non-network services.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you'll need to disable the "System Integration Protection" by following the instructions in [How to Disable System Integrity Protection](https://www.howtogeek.com/230424/how-to-disable-system-integrity-protection-on-a-mac-and-why-you-shouldnt/).

Then unload the mDNSResponder service:

```
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist
```

Insert into "NoMulticastAdvertisements" for configuration:

```
sudo defaults write /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist ProgramArguments -array-add "-NoMulticastAdvertisements"
```

Reload service without Bonjour Advertisement:

```
sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist
```

Comment: ..and then RE-ENABLE SIP.  Any security benefits from disabling mDNS are completely outweighed by the security implications of leaving SIP disabled.  Also note that the solution described here will likely need to be repeated after every single macOS update.

Answer (score 0):

It's now unable to modify
`/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist`

Instead, modify `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist` by the following

`sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist NoMulticastAdvertisements -bool true`

---

https://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=8&topic=mDNSResponder
https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/apple_os_x_10.13/2021-03-29/finding/V-214863