# Macbook Pro 2015 waking from sleep every few seconds

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, sleep-wake

My 2015 Macbook Pro loses charge rapidly while asleep (almost as fast as while it's awake and I'm using it). From looking around online, some people seem to have resolved this by resetting the PRAM - no luck. I checked the sleep settings and they seem to be normal. pmset output is:

```
> pmset -g
System-wide power settings:
Currently in use:
 lidwake              1
 autopoweroff         1
 standbydelayhigh     86400
 autopoweroffdelay    28800
 standbydelaylow      10800
 standby              1
 proximitywake        0
 ttyskeepawake        1
 hibernatemode        3
 powernap             0
 gpuswitch            2
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 highstandbythreshold 50
 displaysleep         2
 sleep                2
 acwake               0
 halfdim              1
 tcpkeepalive         1
 disksleep            10
```

Disabling tcpkeepalive and turning off Find My Mac didn't help the issue. Turning off wifi before closing the lid to let it go into sleep mode still resulted in the same amount of lost charge. In the logs, there are entries like this every few seconds while the laptop is closed and theoretically should be asleep (from running `log show --style syslog | fgrep "Wake reason"`):

```
2020-05-21 15:20:41.355102-0400  localhost powerd[149]: [powerd:sleepWake] Wake reason: "<private>"  identity: "<private>"
2020-05-21 15:20:54.768976-0400  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.DarkPME (Maintenance)
2020-05-21 15:20:54.768979-0400  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.DarkPME (Maintenance)
2020-05-21 15:20:55.772516-0400  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2020-05-21 15:20:55.777431-0400  localhost powerd[149]: [powerd:sleepWake] Wake reason: "<private>"  identity: "<private>"
2020-05-21 15:21:11.717276-0400  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.DarkPME (Maintenance)
2020-05-21 15:21:11.717279-0400  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.DarkPME (Maintenance)
2020-05-21 15:21:12.594368-0400  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2020-05-21 15:21:12.605039-0400  localhost powerd[149]: [powerd:sleepWake] Wake reason: "<private>"  identity: "<private>"
2020-05-21 15:21:25.126875-0400  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.DarkPME (Maintenance)
2020-05-21 15:21:25.126878-0400  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.DarkPME (Maintenance)
2020-05-21 15:21:26.007442-0400  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
```

I assume EC.DarkPME is the culprit here, but I can't figure out what it is or how to get rid of it (if that's the solution). I've seen [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/344093/macbook-wakes-up-unexpectedly-when-the-lid-remains-closed-power-unplugged) question over here, but I don't have bluetooth devices allowed to wake the computer. The computer's running Catalina 10.15.3. Any help would be very appreciated!

*Edit:* I forgot to add another very weird thing that's been happening: if I completely power off the computer and plug it into the charger, it turns back on. The lid is closed, but I can hear the startup chime and see the apple logo light up. When I open it afterwards, it's at the logon screen.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with my 2015 Macbook pro 13. Even if I had turned off tcpkeepalive and power nap, the system was waking up from sleep. In one of my tests I realized that if I close the lid and enter sleep while the charger was plugged in, the system wakes up from sleep, because "Power Adapter" settings are left effective. Eventually, I had to turn off "Wake for Wi-Fi network access" and powernap for both Battery and the Power Adapter modes.

Just to test if this is the issue, can you try to first unplug the laptop from charge, and then close the lid to enter sleep, and see what happens?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be it. Power Nap is disabled for both battery and AC settings, as is Wake for Wi-Fi network access. Closing lid on battery has the same issue as when plugged in to the adapter.